# How to use the pooled-lo optimizer with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jboss, optimization

I have a JBoss 7.1.1 running an EAR that uses the JPA. With the JPA annotation, I use the strategy `GenerationType.Table` which is mapped to the `org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator`.

Does anyone know how to configure the `persistence.xml` when using the "pooled-lo" optimizer?

Answer (score 10):

### TABLE generator is a terrible choice

Now, before I start explaining how you can configure the `pooled` or `pooled-lo` optimizers, you should know that the `TABLE` generator is a terrible choice as not only that it's 10 times slower, but it can congest your database connection pool since it requires an extra connection to fetch the identifier.

More, because it uses row-level locks to allocate the next identifier, this can lead to bottlenecks in your application. For more details about the perils of [`TABLE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) generator.

### Sequence-based optimizers

Starting with Hibernate 5, the `pooled` optimizer is used whenever you are setting the `allocationSize` attribute of the JPA `@SequenceGenerator` annotation to a value that's greater than `1`.

> For Hibernate 4 or 3, to use the `pooled` or `pooled-lo` optimizers, you have to enable the following Hibernate property:
>
> ```
> <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
> ```

It's worth noting that the `pooled` and `pooled-lo` optimizers are only available for SEQUENCE and TABLE generators as the goal of these optimizers is to reduce the number of database roundtrips needed to fetch the next entity identifiers.

### Pooled optimizer

The `pooled` optimizer is very easy to set up. All you need to do is set the `allocationSize` of the JPA `@SequenceGenerator` annotation, and Hibernate is going to switch to using the `pooled` optimizer:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator = "post_sequence"
)
@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "post_sequence",
    sequenceName = "post_sequence",
    allocationSize = 3
)
private Long id;
```

[image: Hibernate pooled optimizere]

Since this mapping is more straightforward, you can switch to `pooled-lo` instead of `pooled` if you also provide this Hibernate configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred" value="pooled-lo" />
```

### Pooled-lo optimizer

To use the pooled-lo optimizer, the entity identifier mapping will look as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator = "pooled-lo"
)
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "pooled-lo",
    strategy = "sequence",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(
            name = "sequence_name",
            value = "post_sequence"
        ),
        @Parameter(
            name = "initial_value",
            value = "1"
        ),
        @Parameter(
            name = "increment_size",
            value = "3"
        ),
        @Parameter(
            name = "optimizer",
            value = "pooled-lo"
        )
    }
)
```

To understand how the pooled-lo works, check out this diagram:

[image: Hibernate pooled-lo optimizer]

> If you have been using the legacy `hilo` optimizer, you might want to switch to using `pooled` or `pooled-lo`, as `hilo` is not interoperable with other clients that might not be aware of the `hilo` identifier allocation strategy.

Comment: `Starting with Hibernate 5, the pooled optimizer is used whenever you are setting the allocationSize attribute of the JPA @SequenceGenerator annotation to a value that's greater than 1.` By default allocation size if 50, so does it pick up pooled optimizer?

Comment: @JavaLearner If you use the default allocation size of 50, you also need to have a matching increment size for the database sequence. Otherwise, it will not work as expected. Hibernate tries to figure out this problem and log a warning message.

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime i got an answer for my question.

When you add the following line to the `<properties>` section in your persistent.xml file, hibernate will use the "pooled-lo" optimizer.

```
<property name="hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.prefer_lo" value="true" />
```

Comment: This is the correct property name for Hibernate 3.6.x. They changed it in 4.x and later I guess, that's why Vlad's answer wasn't working for me. +1